# Azure DevOps default read access to members of organization on new projects

Tags: azure-devops, permissions, user-management

I manage an Azure DevOps organization with a couple dozen users, all with either Visual Studio subscriber or Basic user access level on the organization.

When someone creates a new project, which need to be private repos, I want all the organization users to automatically get read access to see the project and clone repos. Is there a way to do that? Everything works great once we grant the access at the project level, but sometimes people create projects and don't grant the access, so I don't know what projects exist. Do we need to rely on people creating the projects to grant read access to the group of users when they create them?

Comment: `Do we need to rely on people creating the projects to grant read access to the group of users when they create them?`. The answer is yes, we need to rely on people(project creators,admins, org admins) to grant access.

Comment: How about the issue? Does the answer below resolved your question, If not, would you please let me know the latest information about this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When someone creates a new project, which need to be private repos, I
> want all the organization users to automatically get read access to
> see the project and clone repos. Is there a way to do that?

This is **not supported** by design.

To protect private project, Azure Devops doesn't support automatically granting any access of newly created project to those normal Organization-level users unless the users belongs to the PCA (Project Collection Administrators, highest level in whole Org. It shouldn't be granted to normal users).

So we **do** need to rely on people creating the projects to grant read access to the group of users when they create them. Apart from project creators(people creating the projects), PCA or project administrators can also do this job.

You can create a new organization group which contains the Org users:

[image]

Then grant the access to those users by manually adding this group as member of default Project Reader group:

[image]